# Building numpy from source in docker

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, docker

Hi everyone I am trying to build numpy from source in docker container.
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:testing
MAINTAINER Dr Suman Khanal <suman81765@gmail.com>
LABEL updated_at '2017-07-26'
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y gnupg git wget build-essential python3 python3-dev 
python3-setuptools python3-pip libatlas3-base libatlas-dev libatlas-base-dev 
liblapack-dev libblas-common libblas3 libblas-dev cython

RUN git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
WORKDIR /numpy
RUN python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 install 
CMD ["numpy"]
```

But its throwing this error.
`Build failed: The command '/bin/sh -c python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 install' returned a non-zero code: 1` 
Any help?

Many thanks,

Suman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM debian:testing

MAINTAINER Dr Suman Khanal <suman81765@gmail.com>
LABEL updated_at '2017-07-26'

WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y gnupg git wget build-essential python3 python3-dev \
 && apt-get install -y python3-setuptools python3-pip libatlas3-base \
 && apt-get install -y libatlas-dev libatlas-base-dev libblas3 libblas-dev cython

RUN git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
WORKDIR /numpy

RUN python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 install 
RUN pip3 install nose

CMD ["python3", "/numpy/numpy/tests/test_ctypeslib.py"]
```

I tested it with success build and run:

```
$ docker run -it test-numpy
.......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.004s

OK
```

Also I dont know exactly what you want to achieve with `CMD ["numpy"]` because it's directory. I added install `nose` b/c it is required for numpy's test.

You can test and play with numpy in docker:

```
docker exec -it test-numpy bash
```

Comment: Thank you, its working. But I couldn't understand this command `CMD ["python3", "/numpy/numpy/tests/test_ctypeslib.py"]`. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Suman It is just running numpy's test to make sure whether it works. You can define your own command or whatever you need for your requirements.